# Multiple RequiredFieldValidator crashes page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a very strange problem. I've recently added MVC4 to an old Web Forms project. I did this by creating a new project, and adding the old files to the new project (rather than opposite approach of copying the new MVC files in). When I did this, one of my Web Forms pages stopped working - When I try to access it, it redirects to HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

The file is there, and I also have other Web Forms (.aspx) pages that load without any issues. To pin-point the issue, I created a Web Forms page with the same name to replace it, and it the blank page loads. I started adding code to the new page one line at a time till I found the issue.

I finally found that what caused the issue is when I have more than one RequiredFieldValidator tag on the page. Any idea why this would happen or what I can do to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

assign groups to the validators. Put them in separate groups, dont put them in same groups , make sure You dont have controltoassign be same because then during compilation same requiredfield validator might have concurrency issues and crash the page. Putting them in different groups assures that even more. If you still get the same issue then try this as well
Open IIS Manager
Right Click the server name
Select properties
Click the MIME Types button
Click New
Extension is .pdf
MIME type is application/pdf

Comment: I tried putting them in separate groups and had the same problem. Why would I add the .pdf MIME type?